# Select radio button according to value

Tags: c#, datagridview, radio-button

Im trying to make 2 radio buttons "Male" and "Female" so when i open new form radio buttons automaticly get selected according to cell value.

this is code which fills textbox with cell value

```
frm.UGenderBox.Text = ListGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: you can achieve that by validating frm.UGenderBox.Text. if radio buttons present in the same form

Comment: i tried something like this but it doesnt work
if (ListGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value == "Male")
            {
                frm.UMaleRadioBtn.Select();
            }
            if (ListGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value == "Female")
            {
                frm.UFemaleRadioBtn.Select();
            }

Comment: radio button is on other form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i was looking for :)

```
if (ListGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "Male")
        {
            frm.UMaleRadioBtn.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            frm.UFemaleRadioBtn.Checked = true;
        }
```